# Convert Listobject DataBodyRange to an Array issue (only 1 row available)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Never had this issue in my last 6 years of VBA coding and I wonder what the best approach is to handle this situation.

I have a listobject and it varies how many databodyrange rows it contains.
Could be like this:

| Header |
| --- |
| Value1 |
| Value2 |
| Value3 |

or like this:

| Header |
| --- |
| Value1 |

Usually to put the databodyrange to an array I do the following.

```
Dim vValues() As Variant
If tbl.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
vValues= tbl.DataBodyRange
```

But when there is only one row in the databodyrange I get an error 13 - Type Missmatch.
Makes no sense to me why VBA should have a problem with that.
My workaround is the following.

```
Dim vValues() As Variant
If tbl.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count = 1 Then
    ReDim vValues(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    vValues(1, 1) = tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(1, 1)
Else
    vValues= tbl.DataBodyRange
End If
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: If you have one cell, then its Value is not an array, it's just a value. Declare your variable as just a Variant, not an array, and then test with `IsArray` and react accordingly.

Comment: thank you - this one was not on my radar. But then the rest of my approach must still be used right?

Comment: Possibly - it depends what you are doing. :)

Comment: Your workaround is fine - I would put it in a standalone function though: pass in the range and return the array.